# is there a placeholder for src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory in Maven

Tags: maven

Is there a predefined placeholder for src/main/webapp/WEB-INF directory in maven which can be referred by ${XYZ} ?

If not, is there a way to define such a placeholder?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a need for predefined variables that are very much tied to a particular type of project module and packaging standard, with `$basedir` you have access to any module folder you want. So also `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

And Maven allows you to define your own properties.

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <webinf.basedir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</webinf.basedir>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Then you simply have access to the path as `${webinf.basedir}`. Use whatever property name you like of course.

Refer to the Maven documentation for a nice overview of [available path properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide).